# Weird content behavior in Chrome - Flashing

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, settimeout

Is anyone else seeing the flashing behavior of the three buttons/image-sets directly below the  slider here: http://foodforhealthinternational.com/

I don't see it every time and it's only happening in Chrome, but it seems to be related to the following jQuery since the flashes are in sync with this script's setTimeout:

```
function checkForChanges()
{
    if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('right-partner'))
    {
        jQuery("#home-middle-first").css("background-image","url([image path]/turnkey_hover.png)");
        jQuery("#home-middle-second").css("background-image","url([image path]/raw_ing_normal.png)");
        jQuery("#home-middle-third").css("background-image","url([image path]/copack_normal.png)");
    }
    else if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('living-nutrients'))
    {
        jQuery("#home-middle-second").css("background-image","url([image path]/raw_ing_hover.png)");
        jQuery("#home-middle-first").css("background-image","url([image path]/turnkey_normal.png)");
        jQuery("#home-middle-third").css("background-image","url([image path]/copack_normal.png)");
    }
    else if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('with-you'))
    {
        jQuery("#home-middle-third").css("background-image","url([image path]/copack_hover.png)");
        jQuery("#home-middle-first").css("background-image","url([image path]/turnkey_normal.png)");
        jQuery("#home-middle-second").css("background-image","url([image path]/raw_ing_normal.png)");
    }

    setTimeout(checkForChanges, 250);
}
jQuery(checkForChanges);
```

The thing is, this was working fine for more than a day. This might have started in conjunction with a couple of plugins added by others (this is within WordPress).

Anyway, I digging hard for a resolution and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I've replace the [doing stuff] with the actual code. It's basically looking for one of three possible classes that appear in the slider above, then changing the background images for the IDs below based on which class.

**UPDATE 2:**

After taking the advice below, I worked the script to manipulate positioning, rather than call a new image for the background changes. Also, I figured out a way to call the function when each image loads, so no more 1/4 second timer...

Now it simply adds or removes a class that changes the background images position.

```
function checkForChanges()
    {
        if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('right-partner'))
        {
            jQuery("#home-middle-first").addClass("home-middle-hover");
            jQuery("#home-middle-second").removeClass("home-middle-hover");
            jQuery("#home-middle-third").removeClass("home-middle-hover");
        }
        else if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('living-nutrients'))
        {
            jQuery("#home-middle-second").addClass("home-middle-hover");
            jQuery("#home-middle-first").removeClass("home-middle-hover");
            jQuery("#home-middle-third").removeClass("home-middle-hover");
        }
        else if(jQuery("#slider-banner").hasClass('with-you'))
        {
            jQuery("#home-middle-third").addClass("home-middle-hover");
            jQuery("#home-middle-first").removeClass("home-middle-hover");
            jQuery("#home-middle-second").removeClass("home-middle-hover");
        }
    }
```

I am still trying to incorporate some of the other advice, to use the loop and variables, but my attempts to rework the code below failed, (my lack of jQuery skills, not the code).

Comment: Can you post the `[doing stuff]` code? It appears to be making regions of the page re-draw every quarter of a second.

Comment: Whoa, I see what you are saying now, the first time it was having no problems.

Comment: As far as resolution, I would look at developing for 1280x1024. 800x600 is pretty out of date anymore IMO.

Comment: @Jasper - I've added the actual code if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get it the first time, but when I refreshed I did.

This makes me think you have a race condition. Perhaps the first time it took longer for a script file to load than for this to execute, so there wasn't an issue. When I refreshed, it was all pulled from cache and caused the problem. I'm not sure, it's just a hunch, but it's consistent with your intermittent description.

However, I'm going to call for a sanity check on your function... every quarter of a second you are loading the the image for three elements via an http request to a remote server.

There are several ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, I would recommend placing all the images in to a single sprite and then updating the `background-position` property, as opposed to the actual image.

Also, I see that you are trying to tie this in with your slide show animation, but it's not quite exact. Surely whatever you're doing your slideshow with has the ability to use a callback function, so you can trigger this animation only as needed?

Comment: Good feedback Chris. I am actually going to incorporate your positioning suggestion asap. I threw this together at the last minute and knew there would be better ways to do this. Also, haven't looked at the slider close enough yet, but if I can get this added to a callback, even if it didn't get rid of the weird behavior, it would still be better. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris, I posted an updated version of this function that incorporates your "Sanity check" by utilizing background positioning and calls the script when the slide loads, rather than using the timer aspect. I know there are still further ways to fine tune it, but I appreciate your pointing out the "obvious" because I should have known better and gone this direction from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should check if the new source for the background-images are the same, before changing them:

```
//cache all selections that are used each time `checkForChanges()` runs
var $banner = jQuery("#slider-banner"),
    $first  = jQuery("#home-middle-first"),
    $second = jQuery("#home-middle-second"),
    $third  = jQuery("#home-middle-third"),
    convert = [
        {
            class : 'right-partner',
            src   : ['/turnkey_hover.png', 'raw_ing_normal.png', '/copack_normal.png']
        },
        {
            class : 'living-nutrients',
            src   : ['/raw_ing_hover.png', 'turnkey_normal.png', '/copack_normal.png']
        },
        {
            class : 'with-you',
            src   : ['/copack_hover.png', '/turnkey_normal.png', '/raw_ing_normal.png']
        }
    ];

function checkForChanges()
{
    //iterate through each of the classes to check
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        //check if the class at the current index is currently applied to the banner
        if ($banner.hasClass(convert[i].class)) {

            //check to see if the background-images are already set to the current index
            if ($first.css('background-image') != convert[i].src[0]) {

                //if not then change the background-images
                $first.css('background-image', convert[i].src[0]);
                $second.css('background-image', convert[i].src[1]);
                $third.css('background-image', convert[i].src[2]);
            }

            //since we found the class applied to the banner we don't need to run this loop anymore, so stop it
            break;
        }
    }

    setTimeout(checkForChanges, 250);
}
jQuery(checkForChanges);
```

## Update

It took me a while to see what you were doing, instead of polling the page for changes, try to utilize a callback function of your slideshow script instead.

## Update

I pasted my JS code into your site via the JS console, and it stops the constant blinking, however when a slide changes there is a single blink.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the work you put into this. I was away for a few hours and I'm getting ready to dive back into this now so I'll see if I can get this working based on your code. One thing I did already is convert the two images to one single image each that I can manipulate the positioning of, as Chris suggested below.

Comment: Hey Jasper, I got away from timer, like you suggested, but as you can see from my latest update, I haven't been successful adapting your example to my new scenario. I've even tried just adapting the use of variables (something that would have been a no-brainer for me PHP) but no luck yet. I hate to ask you to have another look at it, because you did so much already, but in case you enjoy educating jQuery boneheads like me, any thoughts? Thanks!